# Why can't the nagios user send mails using "sendmail"?

Tags: nagios3, sendmail

I have installed `nagios` for monitoring and `sendmail` for sending mails. When testing from `root` account I am receiving mails, but I'm not receiving mails when I send it from `nagios` account. I have googled and found that only `root` user can send mails using `sendmail MTA`. How to enable `sendmail` to send mails from `nagios` account?

Note that I don't send messages directly from the local machine, but instead use my ISP/provider relay. The below logs show the error from the relay when the message comes from `nagios@`, but not when it comes from `root@`.

#### Output from nagios user:

1. cat /var/log/maillog

   ```
   Sep 19 15:52:32 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[6088]: q8JAMWXZ006088: from=nagios, size=237, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209191022.q8JAMWXZ006088@localhost.localdomain>, relay=nagios@localhost
   Sep 19 15:52:32 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[6089]: q8JAMWCn006089: from=<nagios@localhost.localdomain>, size=517, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209191022.q8JAMWXZ006088@localhost.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
   Sep 19 15:52:32 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[6088]: q8JAMWXZ006088: to=karthick.murugadhas@****.com, ctladdr=nagios (496/492), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30237, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q8JAMWCn006089 Message accepted for delivery)
   Sep 19 15:52:32 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[6091]: q8JAMWCn006089: to=<karthick.murugadhas@****.com>, ctladdr=<nagios@localhost.localdomain> (496/492), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=120517, relay=smtp10.netcore.co.in. [202.162.229.32], dsn=4.7.1, stat=Deferred: 450 4.7.1 <nagios@****.com>: Sender address rejected: Please checked sender domain
   ```

#### Output from root user:

1. cat /var/log/maillog

   ```
   Sep 19 15:43:29 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[5158]: q8JADTt2005158: from=root, size=237, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209191013.q8JADTt2005158@localhost.localdomain>, relay=root@localhost
   Sep 19 15:43:29 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[5159]: q8JADTFO005159: from=<root@localhost.localdomain>, size=511, class=0, nrcpts=1, msgid=<201209191013.q8JADTt2005158@localhost.localdomain>, proto=ESMTP, daemon=MTA, relay=localhost.localdomain [127.0.0.1]
   Sep 19 15:43:29 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[5158]: q8JADTt2005158: to=karthick.murugadhas@****.com, ctladdr=root (0/0), delay=00:00:00, xdelay=00:00:00, mailer=relay, pri=30237, relay=[127.0.0.1] [127.0.0.1], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (q8JADTFO005159 Message accepted for delivery)
   Sep 19 15:43:30 ubuntubackup-chennai sendmail[5161]: q8JADTFO005159: to=<karthick.murugadhas@****.com>, ctladdr=<root@localhost.localdomain> (0/0), delay=00:00:01, xdelay=00:00:01, mailer=relay, pri=120511, relay=smtp10.netcore.co.in. [202.162.229.32], dsn=2.0.0, stat=Sent (_SMR_smtp9.netcore.co.in Ok: queued as 29CE7F6D4C)
   ```

#### Update 1:

`sendmail.mc` configuration file is [here.](http://paste.ubuntu.com/1216437/)

Comment: Sendmail *should* allow non-root users to send as long as the domain is local/you have an FQDN. Can you please pastebin from `/var/log`: `mail.log`, `mail.err`, `mail.info`, `mail.warn`

Comment: It's really hard to try to help without more details on the problem and some logfile. You could try to follow [this thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/nagios-issues-command-but-wont-send-email-778800/) to see what's happening when nagios tries to use `sendmail`, and post back some more info...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Edit: after extensive manual interrogation of your SMTP relay, it looks like the problem may be that the relay specifically blocks `nagios@` as a sender:

```
[izx.I5] ? telnet smtp10.netcore.co.in 25
220 ESMTP
EHLO ********.com
...
MAIL FROM:nagios@********.com
250 2.1.0 Ok
RCPT TO:karthick@********.com
450 4.7.1 : Sender address rejected: Please checked sender domain
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host
```

Does the `nagios@****.com` mailbox exist? Can you try simply rewriting `nagios` to e.g. `nagios1`?

To do this, in `/etc/sendmail.mc` add:

```
FEATURE(`genericstable')dnl
GENERICS_DOMAIN_FILE(`/etc/mail/generics-domains')dnl
```

Create file `/etc/mail/genericstable` and add the line:

```
nagios nagiosk
```

and `/etc/mail/generics-domains` and add lines:

```
localhost
localhost.localdomain
```

Then run `sudo sendmailconfig` and try again.

---

The issue appears to be your SMTP relay at `netcore.co.in`. Hosting/ISP SMTP relays are never "open", and usually set to only relay mails from one of "their" domains and from one of "their" IPs. Mails from `root@localhost` are probably getting through only because some mail  server daemons recognize *root* and make an exception for it, sometimes even replacing the `@localhost` part with whatever the reverse DNS (or IP) of the sender is (for example, my messages once went through in the form of `root@dsl-111-222-111-222.ppp.isp.com`). No such courtesy is afforded to the "nagios@localhost" user.

**Two solutions:**

The easier one may be to simply set (or fake) your sendmail [FQDN](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) to whatever is recognized/authorized by Netcore.

To do this, open `/etc/mail/sendmail.mc` and add these lines at the end before any `MAILER` lines, modifying appropriately:

```
MASQUERADE_AS('karthick.com')
FEATURE(`masquerade_envelope')
```

Then run `sudo sendmailconfig`, answering yes to everything and make sure sendmail is restarted. See [here](http://www.sendmail.com/sm/open_source/docs/m4/masquerading.html) for some more basic info on Sendmail masquerading for relaying.

---

Alternatively, for the sake of completeness, to keep using *nagios@localhost*, you can do one of two things -- either disable relaying in sendmail and use it directly (if you have a static IP/PTR record or RDNS), OR you can set up sendmail to perform SMTP authentication with the Netcore relay.

These Netcore articles may help; you can try asking them too if possible:

- [Why does a sender address get rejected?](http://support.netcore.co.in/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=65)
- [SMTP authentication for Netcore](http://support.netcore.co.in/index.php?_m=knowledgebase&_a=viewarticle&kbarticleid=104)

Comment: @karthick87 can you paste the logs with masquerading enabled?

Comment: The same ones I asked in my original comment to the question: mail.log, mail.err, mail.info, mail.warn . Also include your `sendmail.mc` and `sendmail.cf`.

Comment: @karthick87: this appears to be a problem with the netcore smtp configuration; it seems to disallow `nagios@` addresses. See edit at top to try rewriting it to something different and see if it works.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5885/discussion-between-izx-and-karthick87)

Answer (score 4):

**First of all:** Checking the web arround, and by looking at your logs, it doesn't seem to be an issue with the user nagios, rather, *it seems to be an issue with sendmail's configuration*.

To be more accurate, [a user in this forum](http://forum.powweb.com/archive/index.php/t-44576.html) suggests he gets a similar `450 error code` (he was using postfix, but I assume that there is some kind of protocol) which, as in your situation too, denotes a `domain not found` issue. To quote another user from that same forum:

> This is usually due to a misconfiguration of your e-mail client if the
>   sender address is for a non-existent domain. It could also be, if
>   yours is a new domain, that the receipent's mail server has not caught
>   up with DNS propagation yet.

While you are using localhost as a sender domain, I still believe that there is more that can be taken care of.

As a matter of fact, [another user from another forum I stumbled upon](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-networking-3/%5Bpostfix%5D-sender-address-rejected-domain-not-found-881247/), seems to have *a similar problem to the user in the first forum I linked to, and he too gets the same error code:* `450`. In that same forum another user is quoted suggesting that it is a DNS issue too.

**Important:** I am aware that you are using *localhost* and not a particular domain. **However, to me it seems like it must be an misconfiguration issue of the `sendmail` program, rather than *user nagios* not having rights or anything.**

***I have also found some other sources that I am researching currently. Will continue to update this answer as I get more and more information on the matter.***

**[EDIT #1]:** [Another user in another forum is quoted saying](http://forums.fedoraforum.org/showthread.php?s=7af976eef14cdaf49102d390abfaf3e4&t=126633):

> It appears you are sending from root@machine.mydomaine, when the
>   receiving server does a reverse lookup on this address it will fail as
>   it is not valid and hence the mail will be rejected correctly with the
>   error you have given. Ensure you have a valid server name/domain for
>   your server and that it can be looked up in dns both forward and
>   reverse.

However the user asking the question there doesn't seem to face a `450 error code`. However he gets a similar answer to what I have seen so far on the interwebz.

**[EDIT #2]:** The more I read about your problem, the more I get it: *It seems like `nagios@localhost` that you have selected to use as the domain that sends the emails doesn't resolve to a valid Ip address, and that's what's causing the `smtp10.netcore.co.in` server to respond with a `450 domain not found` response, for it believes that your mail is spam:*

> Yep,"reject_unknown_sender_domain" can cause a lot of false positives,
>   but it does cut down on the spam.

**The most probable fix is to make sure that you use a domain that is resolvable.**

Comment: I dont think so, because i am receiving mail sucessfully when it is send from root user.

Comment: @karthick87 See my last edit.

Comment: @karthick87 And it's not a matter of *what you think it is*, it's a matter of what **your log files are reporting**. The *root@localhost* may be resolving to something different than *nagios@localhost*, if it (nagios) resolves at all. Here is another source I found that could help you clarify what the **450 error code** means, and it also backs my theory: http://systembash.com/content/450-vs-550-smtp-errors/

Comment: So what could be the solution??

Comment: @karthick87 I would suggest setting up sendmail to send mails from a different domain than *localhost*, as it gets filtered out.

Comment: @NlightNFotis: the problem is his (external) SMTP relay; he isn't using his own SMTP server to directly send.

Comment: @izx just saw your answer. It is way more targeted at the problem, but I am happy that I just got to the same conclusion you did =)

Comment: @NlightNFotis: you did a great job troubleshooting, and yes, we came to the same conclusion. I'd suggest removing the part about setting SOA/PTR/MX/etc records from your answer since they don't apply here :)

Comment: @NlightNFotis: no, don't remove it, it's a good answer, +1. I have to sleep, but I have bookmarked it and will definitely edit it tomorrow :)

Comment: @izx done with editing it, hope it makes more sense now =)

Comment: @NlightNFotis Thanks a ton. izx fixed the problem :D He will update the answer shortly..

Comment: @karthick87 Glad to see that you had your issue solved =)

Answer (score 1):

In my nagios configuration the command for sending mail ist

```
/usr/bin/printf "%b" "***** Nagios *****\n\nNotification Type: $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$\n\nService: $SERVICEDESC$\nHost: $HOSTALIAS$\nAddress: $HOSTADDRESS$\nState: $SERVICESTATE$\n\nDate/Time: $LONGDATETIME$\n\nAdditional Info:\n\n$SERVICEOUTPUT$\n" | /usr/bin/mail -s "** $NOTIFICATIONTYPE$ Service Alert: $HOSTALIAS$/$SERVICEDESC$ is $SERVICESTATE$ **" $CONTACTEMAIL$
```

Try out if you can send mail as user nagios from the command line:

```
su nagios
echo "test sendmail" | /usr/bin/mail -s "test" yourmail@domain.tld
```

This may either fail because of a bad path, access rights or the mailserver not accepting the destination address. Please keep us posted on your test results.

Comment: Thankyou Floyd. Pls see the updated questions with required logs..

Answer (score 0):

Sendmail is kinda ancient. While some people think of it as the best mail server ever written, personally I do not enjoy it the least bit.

My combination for sending emails from local user accounts to "external" mail adresses is `postfix` and `bsd-mailx`

If you want to give it a try: `sudo apt-get install postfix bsd-mailx`.

If you do not want to receive any emails on this host, you could make Postfix a little more secure by binding it to localhost. Run `sudo postconf -e 'inet_interfaces = localhost' && sudo service postfix restart`.

Comment: Sorry i dont prefer postfix.

Comment: @pgschk: Did you even read the question?

Comment: Of course I did. I just felt like the focus was on having Nagios send emails, not on using sendmail. So I offered the OPTION to try something that I know for a fact works. That's why I wrote "If you want to give it a try", see?
However if sendmail is so important: I replaced my postfix with sendmail on the Nagios machine, and it works out of the box, so it looks like OP modified something and that broke it.